# How to get paths of files in multiple google shared drive with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

path should be like **shareddrive/folder/abcd.csv** "folder" is a common folder in all the shared drives, if possible I want path of files in that specific folder

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script?

Comment: I didnt have any script with me, can u provide if u have one ?

Comment: I need script to get paths of all files in all shared drives

Answer (score 1):

#### Path for files of All Drives from file Id

```
function getPathAllDrivesFromId(fileid) {
  var ids = [{id:fileid,name:DriveApp.getFileById(fileid).getName()}];
  let r;
  do {
    r = Drive.Files.get(fileid,{supportsAllDrives:true,supportsTeamDrives:true});
    if(r.parents.length > 0) {
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(r.parents[0]));
      ids.push({id:r.parents[0].id,name:DriveApp.getFolderById(r.parents[0].id).getName()});
      fileid = r.parents[0].id
    }
  }while (r.parents.length > 0);
  if(ids[ids.length - 1].name == "Drive") {
    ids[ids.length - 1].name = Drive.Drives.get(ids[ids.length - 1].id).name;
  }
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(ids));
  let path = ids.map(obj => obj.name).flat().reverse().join(' / ')
  Logger.log(path);
  return path;
}
```

Comment: is it filed id or drive id? I need script for paths of all files in all shared drives

Comment: It is filed id.  If you wish to know the path to a file then I need the file id